The elements of a list of length n that take the greatest number of function calls to be found using binary search
I was wondering if there was any information on determining the indices of the elements that take the greatest number of function calls to be found, if binary search is used to find the element, in a list of $n$ elements.
I read somewhere that the number of elements in a list of size $n$, which take the greatest number of function calls to be found is given by $n - 2^{\lfloor \log{n} \rfloor}$ on stack-overflow, if you transform the list to a binary search tree. Is this useful for finding the indices?

The indices that take the longest to reach are the ones at the leaves of the binary search tree. To find them you can simulate the binary search but recurse on both sides of the pivot, until your search range consists of a single index.
